# How can I use multiple VU in k6 to retrieve different IDs from a list API without errors?

Tags: javascript, stress-testing, k6

I want to stress test my website. My process is as follows:

Login
Use the list API to retrieve some IDs
Use the edit API to modify the content of these IDs
Use the delete API to delete these IDs
This process works fine with one VU.

However, when I change it to 3 VUs, the delete API will repeatedly delete IDs that have already been deleted and cause an error. This is not the expected error for my stress test. How can I ensure that each VU gets different IDs when using the list API?

I tried to create an array in the setup, and then put the ID into the array if it was deleted in the default. In this way, I could check if the ID has been deleted. However, it still selects the deleted ID again.

Comment: Arrays (and any state really) are per-VU. If you have 3 VUs, you could calcuate `id % 3` to get your VU id. Only if it matches, delete

Comment: @knittl You really help a lot! I ask ChatGPT-4 and Bard, they don't give me any correct answer and I waste a lot of time. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: I add an if like:  if (id % options.vus === __VU - 1) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Knittl for the answer:
I add a if like:
if (id % options.vus === __VU - 1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).